# Is there a neater way to write a set of time based conditions in js?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Hey so I have the following code but am curious as to whether there is a shorthand or better/neater way to write such a seemingly cumbersome piece of code.

```
var time = new Date().getHours();
var greet;

if ( time >= 0 && time < 4 ) {

    greet = 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.';
}

else if ( time >= 4 && time < 12 ) {

    greet = 'Good morning.';
}

else if ( time >= 12 && time < 17 ) {

    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
}

else if ( time >= 17 && time <= 23 ) {

    greet = 'Good evening.';
}

document.querySelector('.js-greet').innerHTML = greet;
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative

```
let time = new Date().getHours();

let hours = [4, 12, 17, 24];
let greetings = ['Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.', 'Good morning.', 'Good afternoon.', 'Good evening.'];

console.log(greetings[hours.findIndex(hour => hour > time)]);
```

Comment: I like this (ES6) one too!

Comment: This is exactly the type if answer I was hoping for, it's readable enough, it's modern and it's neat and tidy. I will use this solution and polyfill 'findIndex' for those poor souls in IE11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: @matt3224, You get to do what you like. IMO, this sacrifices readability, maintainability, cross-browser compatibility and, probably, speed for being "nifty". Now, if you were encapsulate this such that it was it was actually OOP, or at least used a single object that had `startTime` and `message` properties rather than two separate (global) arrays (which have no inherent relationship), it might have some redeeming features. For doing what you are actually doing, it is a poor choice. [It's not a bad example of something that can be done, it's just not a good choice of what *should* be done.]

Comment: @matt3224, I'm interested in how you intend to polyfill the [`=>` (Arrow functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: I just polyfilled the findIndex function, I also can use Babel to transpile the code should I need to

Comment: @matt3224, chazsolo: minor bug: `let hours = [4, 12, 17, 23];` needs to be `let hours = [4, 12, 17, 24];` (the last entry needs to be larger than 23). As it is, you will get no message from 11PM to 12AM.

Comment: Thanks, I had spotted that ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could -- as an alternative -- define an array with a value per hour. Each value would be an ID of the message to display. This array could even be a string, as strings also allow to access each character via the array notation:

```js
var time = new Date().getHours();

var greet = ['Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.',  
             'Good morning.',
             'Good afternoon.',
             'Good evening.']['000011111111222223333333'[time]];

console.log(greet);
```

Comment: A nice use of a string as a look up table

Comment: While certainly an interesting/instructive alternative, this significantly sacrifices readability/maintainability by putting the hours at which the greeting changes into the `'000011111111222223333333'` string.  In order to understand what is intended, or at least when within the day each greeting is displayed, the person reading the code has to manually *count* the characters in that string.

Comment: I agree, @Makyen, it is just that I got carried away when reading the word "neater" in the question :-) Whether this is "better" is certainly debatable.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need the lower bounds, because `getHours` will never return `< 0` and on the `else if`s, you won't get there if an earlier bound matched; and you don't need any condition on the last one at all, so as a first swing:

```
var time = new Date().getHours();
var greet;

if ( time < 4 ) {
    greet = 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.';
}
else if ( time < 12 ) {
    greet = 'Good morning.';
}
else if ( time < 17 ) {
    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
}
else {
    greet = 'Good evening.';
}

document.querySelector('.js-greet').innerHTML = greet;
```

*(Also removed what seemed to me to be unnecessary vertical whitespace.)*

Other than that, you start getting into maps of messages, by those would be a list of specific hours, not ranges, so probably that's good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simplify your `if` statements considerably due to having already checked (in earlier `if` statements) for the values which are less than the range you desire. In addition, [getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) only returns an integer number between 0 and 23 so there is no reason to check for numbers outside of those bounds.

```js
var time = new Date().getHours();
var greet;

if ( time < 4 ) {
    greet = "Wow you're up late! Good morning.";
} else if ( time < 12 ) {      //You can't get here if time < 4; no need to check again.
    greet = 'Good morning.';
} else if ( time < 17 ) {      //You can't get here if time < 12; no need to check again.
    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
} else {                       //You can't get here if time < 17; no need to check again.
    greet = 'Good evening.';
}

document.querySelector('.js-greet').innerHTML = greet;
```

```html
<div class="js-greet"></div>
```

In addition, you could eliminate the final `else` by assigning `'Good evening.'` to `greet` as the initial value.

```js
var time = new Date().getHours();

var greet = 'Good evening.'; //Remains the value for greet for time >=17
if ( time < 4 ) {
    greet = "Wow you're up late! Good morning.";
} else if ( time < 12 ) {
    greet = 'Good morning.';
} else if ( time < 17 ) {
    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
}

document.querySelector('.js-greet').innerHTML = greet;
```

```html
<div class="js-greet"></div>
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking. :) +!

Comment: Hey @Makyen, I am open to what you would regard as a best practice solution. Am I right in thinking the above is that?

Comment: @matt3224, More complicated than the above (or T.J. Crowder's effectively identical answer) depends on what you are going to use it for (and if what you were requesting was just an example, or actual use). If it is just a one-off that is never going to go live on the web, then whatever you like for the browser you are going to use is fine. If it is something that is going into production code then other considerations come into play. In general, having the strings in a data structure is a good thing (comes closer to being able to be internationalized). (cont.)

Comment: @matt3224, (cont) [chazsolo's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39709276/3773011) could be improved significantly if you encapsulate it in a function like `getGreetingByHour(time)` and changed `hours` to `firstHourOfNextGreeting` (or `greetingLastHours`, subtracting 1 from each entry and changed the test to `hour >= time`), and/or used a single object to hold both the hours and greetings. As it is, `hours` and `greetings` are global & not inherently associated with each other except through proximity. (cont.)

Comment: @matt3224, (cont) Currently, to understand what `hours` *really* is you have to read the code that uses it (and then go back and think "Ahh... OK. So, `hours` is really the first hour of the *next* greeting" and then keep thinking about it that way (i.e. that the corresponding `greetings` entry is actually the next one). From the point of view of someone just reading the code, there is still a question left of if it was really the intent to have the `hours` entry be the first hour of the *next* greeting. It is much better to use a variable name that makes it clear that was the intent. (cont.)

Comment: @matt3224, (cont) RE: ES6 features: Unless you are intentionally limiting the browsers you are running in, then you should only use newer features for which you have to polyfill if they give you a significant advantage (e.g. it is a feature you use multiple times, makes the code more readable/maintainable, etc.).  In other words, using newer features has a cost (possible lack of compatibility, potentially slower (maybe faster where implemented)). You should only accept that cost if it gives you compensating benefits. If you are already using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) then go for it.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen, I am using the flex css module which has limited support for older browsers, this is why I am not too worried about limiting browsers. I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Good on you for asking how to improve! I see code like this all too commonly, and there are many ways to simplify it.

**Your original code**

```
if ( time >= 0 && time < 4 ) {

    greet = 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.';
}

else if ( time >= 4 && time < 12 ) {

    greet = 'Good morning.';
}

else if ( time >= 12 && time < 17 ) {

    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
}

else if ( time >= 17 && time <= 23 ) {

    greet = 'Good evening.';
}
```

**Improved #1**

Here we take some first steps and remove redundant code / simplify things

```
if(time < 0) {
    //dont do anything
}
// now we can take "time >= 0 && " out, making it easier to read
else if (time < 4) {

    greet = 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.';
}
//here, we don't actually need to check if time >= 4, because if it wasn't
//it would have been dealt with by a previous condition
else if (time < 12) {

    greet = 'Good morning.';
}
//and the same for the rest of them
else if (time < 17 ) {

    greet = 'Good afternoon.';
}

//lets keep things consistant by using "time < 24" rather than "time <= 23"
else if (time < 24) {

    greet = 'Good evening.';
}
```

**Improved #2**

A re-structuring can simplify the code even more, so lets throw this code into a function

```
//in this function we can take advantage of the order of operations 
//to simplify further
function getGreeting(time){

    //returning early when things go wrong is always a good idea
    if(time < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    //We dont need 'else' because we are returning when a condition is met,
    //and the app doesn't have a chance to try the other conditionals
    //the less 'else's you have the better the code IMO :)
    if (time < 4) {

        //return our string instead of setting it!
        return 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.';
    }

    if (time < 12) {
        return 'Good morning.';
    }

    if (time < 17 ) {
        return 'Good afternoon.';
    }

    if (time < 24) {
        return 'Good evening.';
    }

}

//then call the function 
greet = getGreeting(time);
```

**Improved #3**

We can do better... with data structures!

```
function getGreeting(time){

    //we still check for stuff that shouldn't happen
    if(time < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    //Here we declare a 'greetings' array. In the array there are objects!
    //each object has a field for time start and end as well as a greeting
    //the thing that makes this approach so neat is that adding more data in
    //the future
    //is dead easy, and the data can now come from a database or whatever
    //you want.
    var greetings = [
        {
            timeStart: 0,
            timeEnd: 4,
            greeting: 'Wow you\'re up late! Good morning.'
        },
        {
            timeStart: 4,
            timeEnd: 12,
            greeting: 'Good morning.'
        },
        {
            timeStart: 12,
            timeEnd: 17,
            greeting: 'Good afternoon.'
        },
        {
            timeStart: 17,
            timeEnd: 24,
            greeting: 'Good evening.'
        }
    ];

    //We can add as many new items to the greetings array without ever
    // touching this again!
    for(var i = 0; i < greetings.length; i++)
    {
        if(time >= greetings[i].timeStart && time < greetings[i].timeEnd)
        {
            return greetings[i].greeting;
        }
    }

}

//then call the function 
greet = getGreeting(time);
```